# How to attach bytebuddy agent when target application load classes from uRLConnection.getInputStream

Tags: byte-buddy, classloading

I made a java agent with bytebuddy. It works well untill target application load classes form uRLConnection.getInputStream. The target app works well without attachment the agent, but shows exception [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException] when the agent attached. 
this is app's classloading line.

```
return this.getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass(string) //string points the name of a byte array.
```

In the application, the classes is provided in the form of byte array from the uRLConnection.getInputStream at runtime and the application loads those at runtime.
The eclipst stacktrace:

```
    [Byte Buddy] COMPLETE client [app.m@7dc3712, null, loaded=false]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kh
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at app.m.loadClass(m.java:22)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at app.appletviewer.b(appletviewer.java:1176)
    at app.appletviewer.a(appletviewer.java:454)
    at Launcher.main(Launcher.java:43)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kh
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at app.u.loadClass(u.java:79)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findSystemClass(Unknown Source)
    at app.m.loadClass(m.java:30)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
```

My agent is:

```
 try {
        new AgentBuilder.Default()
                .with(new AgentBuilder.InitializationStrategy.SelfInjection.Eager())
                .with(AgentBuilder.Listener.StreamWriting.toSystemError())
                .type((ElementMatchers.any()))
                .transform((builder, typeDescription, classLoader, module) -> builder
                        .method(ElementMatchers.any())
                        .intercept(Advice.to(MyAdviser.class))
                ).installOn(instrumentation);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return;
    }
```

I also tried

```
.transform(new AgentBuilder.Transformer.ForAdvice()
                        .include(MyAdviser.class.getClassLoader())
                        .advice(ElementMatchers.any(), MyAdviser.class.getName()))
```

But it doesn't seem to be attached.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be something else here. Try the second form of advice which avoids class loading where a class loading of a system class in an too ealry stage is probably is your problem in the application of loaded advice. Set an `.ignore(none())` matcher for the instrumentation to make the second approach work as boot strap classes like URLConnection are not by instrumented by Byte Buddy in the default configuration.